Horror move with woman chased through a forest by a man wearing black
I'm looking for a horror movie that I remember seeing just one scene of when I was a kid at a sleepover. It felt like it had a "I know what you did last summer" vibe but I know it wasn't that.
The scene was in the woods, and someone wearing black (maybe a cloak?) chased a woman through the trees and caught her. When he got her, he held her in a headlock and you couldn't see his face. I don't remember what they said, but it seemed like the woman knew who he was and why he was trying to get her, and I think the guy was also after other people too.
He demanded some information from her, and when she said she didn't know (or that she was sorry?) he said something along the lines of "you know why you deserve this, I'm taking what you care about most" or something like that. The camera pans up so you only see the tops of the trees, and the woman starts screaming "Not my face! Please not my face!"

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
